# Making a textview global

Tags: java, android

I am wondering if there is any way that you can make a textview visible over every screen so that I don't have to individually create a textview on every activity.

I want to do this so I can display my application version on every screen for debugging.

Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not possible ... but you may build single activity app with fragments ... with main activity layout like: content and "common textview"

Comment: @Selvin Do you know of any way to do it more efficiently then adding it to every activity? Or possibly a library?

Comment: you may also use some BaseActivity class which would add TextView but then it will be new  instance of TextView on every Activity

Comment: You can have a custom theme.Add a `TextView` to the theme and apply this theme to each and every activity.

Comment: @userI any chance you know of any sort of documentation I can work off?

Comment: @userl You can't add a View to a Theme.  A Theme is a set of default properties, it has no visibile elements

Comment: @Gabe Sechan mean to say custom layout.

Comment: @Joshua Best refer the below answer that's what I mean to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! it is possible.

See you have to add this code.

```
<include layout="@layout/layout_version"/>
```

and

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

}
```

**And you will find version text.**

Just add this few code.

> (1) Create a layout that will represent version text.

**layout_version.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" // or match_parent (according to your need)
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVersion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... other properties
        />

    <!--... other component if required-->

</LinearLayout>
```

> (2) Include this to your activity layout like **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   ...>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_version"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> (3) Create a **BaseActivity.class** or add my code if you have already.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.innovanathinklabs.sample.BuildConfig;
import com.innovanathinklabs.sample.R;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tvVersion = findViewById(R.id.tvVersion);
        if (tvVersion != null) tvVersion.setText(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
    }
}
```

> (4) Final step is to extend all your activity by `BaseActivity.class`.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

}
```

That's all!